# problem solving with functions: AMC12 question

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Question: Let $P(n)$ and $S(n)$ denote the product and sum respectively of digits of an integer $n$. For example $P(23)=6$. Suppose $N$ is a two digit number such that $N=P(N)+S(N)$. What is the units digit of $N$?

My logic so far is that if $N$ is a two digit number that means $N$ can be any number from $10$-$99$. So in terms of a function this is: $N=10x+y$

But it's the $P(N)$ and $S(N)$ this is confusing me. I can only guess the $P(N)=xy$ and $S(N)=x+y$ but I just can't explain why this is a shot in the dark.

If I am correct could someone expand on why this is to be correct or if I am wrong could someone point me in the right direction.

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

$$N = 10x + y = xy + x + y$$
$$9x = xy$$
Because this is a two-digit number, $x \gt 0$, and we can divide by $x$
$$y=9$$

Answer (score 0):

You are doing this correctly: any two digit number can be written as:
 $N = 10x+y; x,y \in \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$.

This would indeed mean $P(N) =xy$ and $S(N) = x+y$.

The rest of the problem's solution is:

$10x+y = xy+x+y\\ \rightarrow 9x=xy\\ \rightarrow y =9\\ \therefore N = 19,29,39,49,59,69,79,89,99$.

Note: 0 isn't considered because any number where $x=0$ is not a two digit number and $y=0$ cannot satisfy the equation because $10x+0\not = x+0+0x$ for any $x$ being considered.

Answer (score 0):

$N=10x+y$ where $x\in\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$ and $y\in\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$ Then
$$xy+x+y=10x+y\iff xy=9x$$ Since $x\ne 0$ one has $$y=9$$